# Header not showing in UICollectionViewController Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to add a header to my UICollectionViewController. I have done this all through storyboard. When I run the app it doesn't show up.

This is what I am trying to display in my header:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionReusableView

    header.editProfileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    header.nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    header.nameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser()!["name"] as? String

    header.profilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = header.profilePictureImageView.frame.size.height/2
    header.profilePictureImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    header.profilePictureImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    return header

}
```

I am not seeing any errors on the console nor does the app crash. There is just a white screen with the navigation bars title updated to the users username.

Comment: You are using flow layout right?

Comment: I am not and I'm not sure what that is, sorry this is my first time trying to add a header, thanks!

Comment: In the attribute inspector I have layout set to flow if that is what you mean

Answer (score 8):

if use .xib

```
let nib1:UINib = UINib(nibName: "ScheduleHeaderView", bundle: nil)

self.myCollection.register(nib1, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "ScheduleHeaderView")
```

set size for header

```
let layout = self.myCollection.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 180)
```

UICollectionViewDataSource

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header:ScheduleHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "ScheduleHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleHeaderView

    return header
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips you need to pay attention to what you have to do:

1.Implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout like:

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {}
```

2.register header class before you use :

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(HeaderClass.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
```

in the method ViewDidLoad();

3.set the size in the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout like UITableViewDelegate

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(Config.PHONE_WIDTH, 55)
}
```

4.return your own header like what you already done:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could very well be with the height of the header section. I encountered the similar issue where I was registering the header but then the height was not set.

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //default background color is black
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView.register(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
```

//setting the height helped it in displaying on the page

```
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 180)
```

Answer (score -1):

To show header just make sure you have this code in your code with number "1", like this:

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```